# Using large number in Java

Tags: java, int, biginteger

If I have a number x = 0123456789101112, what number type should I make it? I thought maybe long or double might work since their ranges are quite large, but when I compile the program, it says the value is too large. I did some reading and found out that I can use the BigInteger class. When I made all my values BigInteger, it would still not compile:

```
BigInteger x = new BigInteger("0123456789101112");
BigInteger n = new BigInteger("0");
BigInteger m = new BigInteger("0");
BigInteger count = new BigInteger("0");
for(int i = str2.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    n.add(x.divide(Math.pow(10, i)));
}
for(int i = str2.length() - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
    m.add(x.divide(Math.pow(10, i)));
    if(x.divide(Math.pow(10, i)) > 4) {
        count.add("1");
    }
}
```

The errors I get are all the same and occur in the line where I use the Math.pow() methods. The error says that double cannot be converted to BigInteger. how can I fix this problem?

Comment: You can't use Math.pow, or any other standard math operators with BigIntegers. BigIntegers have their own methods that you need to use. Also, if you get errors, and they're relevent to the question, you need to post them. Don't make us guess.

Comment: Keep in mind that prepending a primitive with a `0` will create it in octal (base-8).

Comment: Also note that `m.add(....);` won't work: BigIntegers are immutable. You must do something like: `m = m.add(....);`

Answer (score 2):

`Math.pow` returns a double which cannot cast to BigInteger but BigInteger.divide takes a BigInteger.

So use `BigInteger.valueOf((long)Math.pow(10, i))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the methods for BigIntegers:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Math.pow() is for double.

Also, nesting things makes it hard to debug.  You might consider breaking them up into intermediate steps of the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Use primitive **long** or its wrapper **Long**